# on_member_join discord

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py, python-3.8

I am programming a bot.
How can I use `on_join_member` 2 times or merge these commands?

```
    @client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Welcome To Mafia Server, Be carefully or you will die", color=random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF))
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    embed.set_author(name=member.name, icon_url=member.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=member.guild, icon_url=member.guild.icon_url)
    channel = client.get_channel(id=707680063809650759)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)

    @client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Welcome To Mafia Server", url="https://discord.gg/XyHJRz", description="شرح عن السيرفر", color=0xff0000)
    embed.set_author(name="Meow | مياو", url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/385483285930835979/fa4ed0c7c693f0b4d8cc71760ee01362.png?size=1024", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/385483285930835979/fa4ed0c7c693f0b4d8cc71760ee01362.png?size=1024")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/723170182314328074/2cb64fad48f22df70bd05c75d4b0140b.png?size=1024")
    embed.add_field(name="لا يدخل في السيرفر الا الناس الموثوق بهم", value="لهذا التزموا بالقوانين", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="في هذا السيرفر نقوم بالتنمر على سيرفرات اخرى", value="حيث نذهب عندهم ونتنمر عليهم حتى نأكل منهم كيك او باند او حتى نطفش", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="ونتمنى لكم", value="حياة هنيئة دون قتالات بالسيرفر", inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text="وفي النهاية كلوا رز ولبن")
    await member.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing something as simple as this should work

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Welcome To Mafia Server, Be carefully or you will die", color=random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF))
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    embed.set_author(name=member.name, icon_url=member.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=member.guild, icon_url=member.guild.icon_url)
    channel = client.get_channel(id=707680063809650759)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)

    embed=discord.Embed(title="Welcome To Mafia Server", url="https://discord.gg/XyHJRz", description="شرح عن السيرفر", color=0xff0000)
    embed.set_author(name="Meow | مياو", url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/385483285930835979/fa4ed0c7c693f0b4d8cc71760ee01362.png?size=1024", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/385483285930835979/fa4ed0c7c693f0b4d8cc71760ee01362.png?size=1024")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/723170182314328074/2cb64fad48f22df70bd05c75d4b0140b.png?size=1024")
    embed.add_field(name="لا يدخل في السيرفر الا الناس الموثوق بهم", value="لهذا التزموا بالقوانين", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="في هذا السيرفر نقوم بالتنمر على سيرفرات اخرى", value="حيث نذهب عندهم ونتنمر عليهم حتى نأكل منهم كيك او باند او حتى نطفش", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="ونتمنى لكم", value="حياة هنيئة دون قتالات بالسيرفر", inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text="وفي النهاية كلوا رز ولبن")
    await member.send(embed=embed)
```